# Python unittest mock fails for another module

Tags: python, sympy, python-unittest

I try to mock `simplify_logic` method from [sympy python library](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

```py
mock = MagicMock(sympy.logic.boolalg.simplify_logic)
```

The mock has been failing with the following  message pointing to another module.

```py
AttributeError: module 'sympy.core.logic' has no attribute 'boolalg'
```

I also try `@patch` but I got the same error.

How can this mocking issue be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The module under test was another module referred. That module was using the `sympy` library.

When I change the mock to refer to the module under test, the mock worked.

`with patch('module_under_test.simplify_logic') as simplify_logic_mock:`